# Mic/Audio doesn't work when using Webcam

Tags: drivers, audio, webcam, microphone

I recently got a Thinkpad T420 laptop with a webcam. The audio and microphone work fine as long as I'm not using the webcam. However, when I use a program like Skype or Windows Live Messenger to video chat, the programs say that the audio/mic don't work. Does anyone have clues as to what to do in this situation?

Comment: As an additional note when I start using Skype, other programs such as Chrome will not play any audio until I close the webcam app and restart the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like whenever the webcam is activated, all sound our your system is killed. You mentioned audio in Chrome but just to make sure, if you are listening to music does it also die when the webcam turns on?

Best piece of advice: update your drivers. Go to Lenovo's [support site](http://support.lenovo.com) and install the latest drivers for your webcam (look for "Integrated Camera Driver" under Multimedia if you can't find it). While you are there, install the latest drivers for your soundcard as well.

Answer (score -3):

It is due to the default microphone device selected in Skype/call settings.
Also if you have Conexan smart audio driver, it is also because of it. I have to select manually the speakers and microphone device every time because of the audio driver. I use the multi-stream audio.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. For your answer to be complete, please provide instructions on how to *solve* the problem based on this information.